# Date Time Format Trouble

Tags: pandas, datetime, strftime, string-to-datetime

I'm having some troubles with Datetime formats. My database comes with this datetime format:

"2020-11-01T03:17:54Z"

Thing is that I just can't find the format that fits this string in order for me to convert it to a datetime object.  I've gone all over the documentation but I just can´t find how to write the "T" or what the "Z" means.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You'll find the format as ISO 8601 / RFC 3339. For parsing to datetime in Python, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/62769371/10197418 - or in pandas just use pd.to_datetime and auto-detect the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date is in ISO 8601 format.
If you try:

```
    mydate = "2020-11-01T03:17:54Z"
    mydate_updated = pd.to_datetime(mydate)
```

you will see that this format includes the info "tz='UTC'":

```
    Timestamp('2020-11-01 03:17:54+0000', tz='UTC')
```

You can remove it (but keep that the date is in UTC) as follows:

```
    mydate_updated = pd.to_datetime(mydate).tz_localize(None)
```

The result will be the timestamp:

```
   Timestamp('2020-11-01 03:17:54')
```

Comment: thanks a lot.  So, how  can i Know the TZ of a string? for example "2020-11-01T03:17:54Z, ¿where can I See is UTC? ¿Is it somewhere hidden in the text?

Comment: Actually the T separates the date from the time and the Z ("Zulu") in the end means UTC

Comment: You can also verify/see that tz is UTC by applying pd.to_datetime on the date, as shown in the answer:)